# Extracting data from a single variable to multi variable- multi observations by symbols and text. [{..]}

Tags: html, r

I have a CSV, extracted from an HTML site, many columns hold a lot of information in one cell. for example- this text is from one cell. It holds the name of 3 companies:

```
[{"company":"Orange","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz","positions":[{"title":"CEO","subtitle":"honelulu","description":"","duration":"Dec 2021 - Present 7 months"}] ,"industry":"Non-profit Organizations"},{"company":"Fig","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz2","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Fig","duration":"Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months",}],},
{"company":"Papaya","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz3","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Pragaya","description":"","duration":"Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months",}],"industry":"High Tech"},}]
```

- I would like to extract each company into a different row, with the user name, position, duration and industry in different columns.
- I also have other date in other columns that I wish would stay the same.

Any ideas for a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This `tidyr` approach with `extract` works for a start:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(dat) %>%
  # simplify:
  mutate(dat = gsub('["\\]\\[}{]', '', dat, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  # separate:
  separate_rows(dat, sep = '(?<!^)(?=company)') %>%
  # extract:
  extract(dat, "company", "company:([^,]+).*", remove = FALSE) %>%
  extract(dat, "user_name", ".*url:([^,]+).*", remove = FALSE) %>%
  extract(dat, "position", ".*\\btitle:([^,]+)", remove = FALSE)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  industry                 duration                              position                     user_name        company
  <chr>                    <chr>                                 <chr>                        <chr>            <chr>  
1 Non-profit Organizations "Dec 2021 - Present 7 months "        CEO                          https://www.xyz  Orange 
2 NA                       "Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months" Business Development Manager https://www.xyz2 Fig    
3 High Tech                "Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months"         Business Development Manager https://www.xyz3 Papaya
```

Data:

```
dat <- '{"company":"Orange","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz","positions":[{"title":"CEO","subtitle":"honelulu","description":"","duration":"Dec 2021 - Present 7 months"}] ,"industry":"Non-profit Organizations"},{"company":"Fig","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz2","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Fig","duration":"Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months",}],},{"company":"Papaya","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz3","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Pragaya","description":"","duration":"Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months",}],"industry":"High Tech"},}]'
```

See also [Use tidyr's function `extract` with optional capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73927505/use-tidyrs-function-extract-with-optional-capture-group/73928900#73928900) for a more elegant solution