# Use tidyr's function `extract` with optional capture group

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

This question relates directly to that question [Extracting data from a single variable to multi variable- multi observations by symbols and text. [{..]}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73926299/extracting-data-from-a-single-variable-to-multi-variable-multi-observations-by/73927067#73927067) where I've been struggling to use `extract` with an optional capture group (and have instead resorted to multiple targeted `extract` operations).

Say I want to extract from this string:

```
dat <- '{"company":"Orange","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz","positions":[{"title":"CEO","subtitle":"honelulu","description":"","duration":"Dec 2021 - Present 7 months"}] ,"industry":"Non-profit Organizations"},{"company":"Fig","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz2","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Fig","duration":"Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months",}],},{"company":"Papaya","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz3","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Pragaya","description":"","duration":"Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months",}],"industry":"High Tech"},}]'
```

five variables: "company", "user_name", "position", "duration",  and "industry" but one of the strings does not have data for "industry". That variable, then, (I guess) will have to be defined as an optional capture group in the `regex`argument. With this code, I feel I'm close - but apparently not close enough, as `industry` returns empty strings for all three strings:

```
data.frame(dat) %>%
  # simplify:
  mutate(dat = gsub('["\\]\\[}{]', '', dat, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  # separate:
  separate_rows(dat, sep = '(?<!^)(?=company)') %>%
  extract(dat,
          into = c("company", "user_name", "position", "duration", "industry"),
          regex = 'company:([^,]+).*?url:([^,]+).*?\\btitle:([^,]+).*?duration:([^,]+).*?(?:industry:(.*))?') 
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  company user_name        position                     duration                              industry
  <chr>   <chr>            <chr>                        <chr>                                 <chr>   
1 Orange  https://www.xyz  CEO                          "Dec 2021 - Present 7 months "        ""      
2 Fig     https://www.xyz2 Business Development Manager "Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months" ""      
3 Papaya  https://www.xyz3 Business Development Manager "Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months"         ""
```

How can this `regex` be tweaked so that it captures the "industry" information where present?

Comment: Just add `$` at the end of the regex to match up to the end of string. If you want to omit the trailing text if there can be any, use `company:([^,]+).*?url:([^,]+).*?\\btitle:([^,]+).*?duration:([^,]+)(?:.*?industry:([^,]*))?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TsM5WD/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
company:([^,]+).*?url:([^,]+).*?\btitle:([^,]+).*?duration:([^,]+)(?:.*?industry:([^,]*))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TsM5WD/1). In R, do not forget to double escape the backslash.

The main point of interest here is `(?:.*?industry:([^,]*))?`, that is an optional non-capturing group (`(?:...)?`) thst matches one or zero occurrences of

- `.*?` - zero or more chars as few as possible
- `industry:` - a literal string
- `([^,]*)` - Group 5: any zero or more chars other than a comma.

R test:

```r
library(tidyr)
dat <- '{"company":"Orange","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz","positions":[{"title":"CEO","subtitle":"honelulu","description":"","duration":"Dec 2021 - Present 7 months"}] ,"industry":"Non-profit Organizations"},{"company":"Fig","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz2","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Fig","duration":"Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months",}],},{"company":"Papaya","location":"","url":"https://www.xyz3","positions":[{"title":"Business Development Manager","subtitle":"Pragaya","description":"","duration":"Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months",}],"industry":"High Tech"},}]'
data.frame(dat) %>%
    # simplify:
    mutate(dat = gsub('["\\]\\[}{]', '', dat, perl = TRUE)) %>%
    # separate:
    separate_rows(dat, sep = '(?<!^)(?=company)') %>%
    extract(dat,
            into = c("company", "user_name", "position", "duration", "industry"),
            regex = 'company:([^,]+).*?url:([^,]+).*?\\btitle:([^,]+).*?duration:([^,]+)(?:.*?industry:([^,]*))?')
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  company user_name        position                     duration                              industry                  
  <chr>   <chr>            <chr>                        <chr>                                 <chr>                     
1 Orange  https://www.xyz  CEO                          "Dec 2021 - Present 7 months "        "Non-profit Organizations"
2 Fig     https://www.xyz2 Business Development Manager "Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months" ""                        
3 Papaya  https://www.xyz3 Business Development Manager "Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months"         "High Tech"               
>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate option would be to get the output in the long format first with `separate_rows`, then split into two columns ('key', 'value'), and then use `pivot_wider` to reshape back to wide

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
 data.frame(dat) %>%  
  mutate(dat = gsub('["\\]\\[}{]', '', dat, perl = TRUE)) %>%  
  separate_rows(dat, sep = '(?<!^)(?=company)') %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(dat, sep = ",") %>% 
  filter(str_detect(dat,
    str_c(c("company", "url", "\\btitle", "duration", "industry"), collapse = "|"))) %>% 
  separate(dat, into = c("key", "value"), sep = ":",
      fill = "right", extra = "merge") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>%  
  select(company, user_name = url, position = positions,
    duration, industry) %>% 
  mutate(position = trimws(position, whitespace =".*:"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  company user_name        position                     duration                              industry                
  <chr>   <chr>            <chr>                        <chr>                                 <chr>                   
1 Orange  https://www.xyz  CEO                          "Dec 2021 - Present 7 months "        Non-profit Organizations
2 Fig     https://www.xyz2 Business Development Manager "Feb 2019 Dec 2021 2 years 11 months" <NA>                    
3 Papaya  https://www.xyz3 Business Development Manager "Jan 2018 Oct 2018 10 months"         High Tech
```